# Laravel Juploader bundle using composer

Tags: php, laravel

Ok i found in other questions in stackoverflow, that artist bundles are not good any more, that you may use composer. but i cant install juploader.

```
php artisan bundle:install juploader
```

USING this trhow:

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                
  There are no commands defined in the "bundle" namespace.
```

http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/juploader

is this really necesary or i just need to insert the next line in bundle.php (creating one?)

```
'juploader' => array('handles' => 'upload'),
```

I need to install juploader, or the best jquery upload file for laravel, that make life easy, XD jaja not more complicated. in the past juploader was easy to install, but im afraid is out of date now.

How can i install this, or maybe there is a newer one that works like charm on 4.1 laravel?

Comment: Bundles don't exist in Laravel 4. Neither does `bundle.php`

Comment: Thanks! i found that out already, im looking on how to install this now. Thanks :D

Comment: Since this bundle is for a previous version, I don't think it's gonna work even if you manage to install it.

Comment: yes i have found this =) https://coderwall.com/p/v21-yw